# Summarize rows of a data frame

Tags: r, plyr

Is it possible to get the same result of `ret` with aggregate or ddply in a more readable way?

```
time<-c("2013-08-05 15:44:19","2013-08-05 15:44:24","2013-08-05 15:45:19","2013-08-05 15:45:28")

df<-data.frame(time=as.POSIXct(time),col2=c(1,2,2,2),col3=LETTERS[1:4])
mm<-split(df,df[,"col2"])
ret<-lapply(mm, function(x){
              mt<-max(x[,"time"])
              idx<-x[,"time"]==mt
              x[idx,]
            }
           )
do.call("rbind",ret)
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain in plain english what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 4):

With `plyr` :

```
R> ddply(df, "col2", summarize, time=max(time))
  col2                time
1    1 2013-08-05 15:44:19
2    2 2013-08-05 15:45:28
```

With `data.table` :

```
R> dt <- data.table(df, key="col2")
R> dt[,list(time=max(time)),by=col2]
   col2                time
1:    1 2013-08-05 15:44:19
2:    2 2013-08-05 15:45:28
```

Comment: +1 for the `data.table` solution. `plyr` seems to be the slowest of all in my benchmarking on huge data. with `data.table` being the fastest.

Comment: I knew the `data.table` solution would please you :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(time~col2, FUN=max, data=df)[, c(2,1)]
                 time col2
1 2013-08-05 15:44:19    1
2 2013-08-05 15:45:28    2
```

with `ddply`

```
> ddply(df, .(col2), summarise, time=max(time))[, c(2,1)]
                 time col2
1 2013-08-05 15:44:19    1
2 2013-08-05 15:45:28    2
```

Just for fun, another base solution using `lapply` and `split`

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(with(df, split(df, col2)),
+                       function(x) x[which.max(x$time), ]))
                 time col2
1 2013-08-05 15:44:19    1
2 2013-08-05 15:45:28    2
```

**Update**

The last solution works for your update

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(with(df, split(df, col2)),
+                       function(x) x[which.max(x$time), ]))
                 time col2 col3
1 2013-08-05 15:44:19    1    A
2 2013-08-05 15:45:28    2    D
```

Comment: Thx, if I would have more columns (I edit the start post) in df, how to select them for return value? And how could I return the result in the order of time?

Comment: Can you update your question with the info in your comment and make it reproducible?

Comment: But now I am not sure if max is computing on the time column in `aggregate(.~col2, FUN=max, data=df)`.